# How to disable drivers on offline Windows 8.x?

Tags: windows, windows-8, boot, drivers, safe-mode

I have the same scenario that [this user so excellently delineated on his "black screen of death" experience](https://superuser.com/questions/818449/windows-8-1-black-screen-and-no-safe-mode).

*Ultimately the crux of the issue seems as though there is no way to bring up safemode or bypass the drivers.*

The only thing that comes to my mind is **manually disabling the video driver** so as to force Windows into using a default driver in order to then get into Safe Mode to then rollback to the previous driver.

How would one go about manually removing a driver once you have such a system's drive removed and able to be manipulated via another workstation?

Comment: You should put a bounty on the existing question instead of asking it again.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 that would significantly diminish my accumulated points as I understand it.  I certainly hate to drop my score below 100 at the moment with any ramifications that may come therefrom.  Further, this isn't a re-ask per se, but I believe that removing the drivers is disconnected enough (while being a solution) that it merits its own focus.

Comment: "that would significantly diminish my accumulated points as I understand it.", and you're going to use the points for what else exactly? It's not like you can cash them in for money or prizes. ;)  I see what you're suggesting about your specific plan... and there's a dupe for that that too. :)

Comment: LOL good catch @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007... But I wonder how applicable to this scenario with Windows 8 that will be... Hmm, going to have to go digest it and see.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 so FYI, my question is still valid.  This solution that you note does not appear to be working out in this case for disabling the driver(s) via ERD on 8.x.  We really need a shell / `cmd` based solution to this problem that is workable by deletion of driver files, etc.

Comment: Here's a compromise – I bountied the other question for you. I have a bit of reputation to spare with no use, really. If there's no answer, we'll see…